# Explain Different Dialog Appearances?

Tags: extensions, jquery, modal

I'm having a problem with a modal dialog. It's not displaying consistently, and I'm not understanding the issue.

If you go to this page:

http://joomla.connectdaily.com/index.php/calendar

click on one of the Colorado Rockies events. Note how the Rockies logo encroaches down into the footer div with the close button. Now, click on the "Corner Store Country Run" event on the 9th. Note that the dialog is sized appropriately, and doesn't encroach. I've put a console.log in place to dump the value of myDialog.

Can anyone give me an idea on what I'm doing wrong here? I'm not "certain", but I'm pretty sure this behavior wasn't present in 3.5.x.

Comment: I feel for you on this. I too am having some issues with one of my extensions on J3.6 cause they messed things up in the update. I would suggest contacting the developers of JEvents if you haven't already to see if they can shed any light on the matter

Comment: Actually, this is my calendar plugin Connect Daily. I guess I'm not the only one bitten by 3.6 changes. Another one that got me was they added gzip/deflate handling for JHttpResponse and my code was already handling it.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that the Rockies logo is an SVG, while the other image is a JPG. I'm think the browser's layout engine may be messing up even though there are height/width elements in the image's style attribute.